# ls: Operation not Permitted

Tags: unix, fuse

I have a running a fuse fs with options allow_other and umask 0. This gives me a set of files with permissions set to 777. Though when I try to `ls -l` in the directory containing the files I get the following output:

```
ls: name: Operation not permitted
ls: tags: Operation not permitted
ls: location: Operation not permitted
ls: ext: Operation not permitted
ls: experiment_id: Operation not permitted
ls: file_path: Operation not permitted
```

Can anyone tell me why despite having global permissions (777) I am still getting operation not permitted?

On running strace, I get the following traces:

```
lstat("tags", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lgetxattr("tags", "security.selinux", 0x112ae80, 255) = -1 EPERM (Operation not     permitted)
write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )                     = 4
write(2, "tags", 4tags)                     = 4
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
lstat("location", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lgetxattr("location", "security.selinux", 0x112aea0, 255) = -1 EPERM (Operation not      permitted)
write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )                     = 4
write(2, "location", 8location)                 = 8
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
lstat("ext", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lgetxattr("ext", "security.selinux", 0x112aec0, 255) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )                     = 4
write(2, "ext", 3ext)                      = 3
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
lstat("experiment_id", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lgetxattr("experiment_id", "security.selinux", 0x112aee0, 255) = -1 EPERM (Operation not    permitted)  
write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )                     = 4
write(2, "experiment_id", 13experiment_id)           = 13
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
lstat("file_path", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lgetxattr("file_path", "security.selinux", 0x112af00, 255) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )                     = 4
write(2, "file_path", 9file_path)                = 9
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

So from the trace, it looks like its trying to get the selinux attribute even though its disabled on my system.

```
cat /etc//sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: Setting `777` permissions is almost always a bad idea; it permits any user on the system to modify the corresponding file or directory. `755` or, at most, `775` is more sensible.

Comment: I can set it to 755. I set it to 777 just to check various debuggin scenarios. Right now I am more interested in finding how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my getxattr implementation. I was returning -1 on error which translated to EPERM, instead I should have returned ENODATA which is more correct error case for my logic. This fixed those errors as well.

https://gowalker.org/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse

Answer (score 16):

**follow the below steps to resolve the issue. I tried below steps, worked for me**
1.Pull down the  Apple menu and choose ‘System Preferences’
2.Choose “Security & Privacy” control panel
3.Now select the “Privacy” tab, then from the left-side menu select “Full Disk Access”
4.Click the lock icon in the lower left corner of the preference panel and authenticate with an admin level login
5.Now click the [+] plus button to add an application with full disk access
6.Navigate to the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and choose “Terminal” to grant Terminal with Full Disk Access privileges
7.Relaunch Terminal, the “Operation not permitted” error messages will be gone

Answer (score 2):

Set permissions on the *directory* that contains the files.

Comment: It is a directory, not a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) at least as

```
 strace ls -l
```

this will show you all the syscalls done by `ls` and you would recognize which FUSE file-system related [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are failing.

<sup>Perhaps [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) is failing on individual directory entries like `tags` etc...?</sup>

You are probably forgetting to implement some operations in your FUSE.

Comment: Updated the question with strace output. The issue seems to be with fetching the selinux attribute.